# My activity is unable to resolve a symbol to the layout file

Tags: android

I have the following activity

```
package com.example.responsivelayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayText extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaytext);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.responsivelayout.MESSAGE");

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_text);
        tv.setText(message);
    }
}
```

But the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_displaytext);` gives error as "cannot resolve symbol". I have the following layout file as `activity_displaytext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

which is present in the layout/ folder. After trying all the efforts, i am clueless why i am getting this error. I tried project clean, make, eveything. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Try Rebuilding,Cleaning and Invalidating Caches/Restart

Comment: Test case try with `invalid - cache and restart studio`

Comment: @SumitShukla : Thanks . File > Invalidate Cache / Restart helped. Now I do not see the issue. But this seems to be a bug and I never expected this issue. It easily wasted more than an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure below **import** is not there

```
import android.R; //Resource class
```

It may be issue with **import**

Import should be

```
import com.example.responsivelayout.R;
```